# Practicing recursion with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, recursion, reinventing-the-wheel, dom

I'm trying to get a good grasp on recursion by implementing `document.getElementsByClassName`. I've made something that works but I'd like to know if there is some blatant refactoring that should be done or perhaps some not-so-edge cases that might break it.

```js
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
  var result = [];
  function diveIn(motherNode, result, className){
    var maNodes = motherNode.childNodes
    for (var i = 0; i < maNodes.length; i++){
        var classes = maNodes[i].classList || [];
        classes.forEach(function(classy){
            if (classy === className){
                result.push(maNodes[i]);
            }
        })
        if (maNodes[i].childNodes[0]){
            diveIn(maNodes[i], result, className);
        }
    }
  }
  diveIn(document, result, className);
  return result;
};
```

Comment: You'd better not to use recursive function for className.This is because if you have to search many times you will exceed maximum call stack size

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what cssGEEK pointed out, your code cannot work at all, since `maNodes[i].classList` doesn't return an Array but a DOMTokenList, which has no `forEach()` method.

So I'm surprised you said it works: it can happen only when no class is defined for an element (then your `|| []` makes `classes` to be an Array), but for each element having class(es) it fires an error "classes.forEach is not a function".

Here is a slighthly different code to achieve what you planned using the same way:

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
  var result = [];
  function diveIn(motherNode, result, className){
    var maNodes = motherNode.childNodes
    for (var i = 0; i < maNodes.length; i++){
        var classes = maNodes[i].classList;
        if (classes && classes.contains(className)) {
            result.push(maNodes[i]);
        }
        if (maNodes[i].childNodes[0]){
            diveIn(maNodes[i], result, className);
        }
    }
  }
  diveIn(document, result, className);
  return result;
};
```

You can look at it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ee7pamom/).

But again don't forget that depending of how heavy is the HTML document it may encounter a max call stack size condition.